# A conjugate LT in an inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space. 
Let $J$ be a conjugate linear map from $V$ to $V$ such that $J^2 =1$.

Can we say  $\langle Ju, Jv \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle$ for all $u, v$ in $V$?

Conjugate linear means $J(u+v) = J(u) + J(v)$ and $J(a.v) = \overline{a}.J(v)$

Comment: What is conjugate linear ?

Comment: sorry J not linear operator may imply J(u+w)=J(u)+J(w) @user1952009. See your example itself there is no problem.

Comment: No I mean same. V is COMPLEX IPS. J is antilinear map(if you familiar with this word). and $J^2=I$. Can we say $<Ju, Jv> = <v , u>$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map edit your question to include that and say that $J$ is NOT a linear operator $V \to V$

Comment: @user1952009 conjugate linear is common ...

Comment: and the answer is easy when considering the underlying real vector space of twice dimension

Comment: sorry but why I have to include J not linear.(let it be both) and what is the answer? @user1952009

Comment: you know that $\mathbb{C}^n$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ ?

Comment: Yes then what @user1952009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in general wrong. Consider on $V=\mathbb C^2$ the antilinear mapping
$$ J(z) = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}}_{=:A} \bar z. $$
Then, we have
$$ J^2(z) = A\overline{(A \bar z)} = A\bar A z = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -i + i \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} z = z$$ and
$$ \langle J e_1, Je_2 \rangle = (A \bar e_1)^H (A \bar e_2) = (A e_1)^H (A e_2) = 1\cdot i + 0\cdot 1 = i \ne 0 = \langle e_2, e_1 \rangle. $$

As asides:

1. Every antilinear mapping on $\mathbb C^n$ looks like $z\mapsto A\bar z$.
2. $A$ is symmetric(!) if and only if $J$ has the mentioned property:
   $$ \langle J(u), J(v) \rangle = \langle A\bar u, A \bar v \rangle = \langle \bar u, A^H A \bar v \rangle = \langle \bar u, \bar v \rangle = \langle v, u \rangle $$
   holds for every $u,v$ if and only if $A^H A = I$. That is $\bar A = A^{-1} = A^H = \bar A^T$. That is, $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: @Sushil: I expanded the answer for you

Comment: thanks. But can you explain your aside 2 mentioned

Comment: @Sushil: There was a error in item 2. I corrected it.

Comment: sorry but what is this H notation. I mean $A^H$

Comment: @Sushil hermitian or complex conjugate transposed

Comment: Thanks a lot. It clears all doubts. Except one new problem. If T is linear transformation such that $JTJ = T$ with J anti-linear map with $J^2 = I$ . Can we find K antilinear with $K^2 = I$ and $<Ku, Kv> = <v, u>$ such that $KTK = K$. Leading me to question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1678399/168520

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36430/discussion-between-sushil-and-user251257).

Comment: $A \overline A$ should be $I$ not what you have written

Comment: @Sushil eh where? In the counter example? $A\bar A$ is $I$.